# How to add calculated text fields in woocommerce add product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, calculated-field

I am working woocommerce v2.2.11. I like to add extra text fields under the Regular Price & Sale Price fields in Add New Product Page. The newly added fields contains custom values like 5% or 2% etc... When admin enters the product regular price, the price should be calculated with newly added text fields value.

For Example...
Regular Price(Rs) : 100
Text Field 1      : 5%  (5% of 100 is 5)
Text Field 2      : 2%  (2% of 100 is 2)
Text Field 3      : 107 (Regular Price + Text Field 1 + Text Field 2)

Note: Text Field 3 should automatically calculated when admin enters Regular Price Value.

How to achieve this....?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should ask this question at [WordPress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) to get proper answer.

I have some idea for you -

1) You can follow this article to add new fields you want on edit product page - http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

2) On keyup event, write jQuery code to perform calculations for the newly added fields.